# What exactly does Typescript / Java script array.find() returns?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have the next line in Typescript

```
const addressFound: AddressPrimary = <AddressPrimary>(this.addressArray.find(addr => addr.id === id));
```

`AddressPrimary` is a class that has a few variables in it one of them is `id: number` another one is `city: number` and there are more some of them are strings.

What exactly will the variable `addressFound` hold when the line is done?

Will it hold a pointer to the class/data?

I'm asking because the method that holds this line "returns (addressFound)" and somewhere along the line I have a line `myAddress: AddressPrimary = method(id)` and now when I do `myAddress.id = 7;` the relevant class in array `addressArray` changes so id gets the value 7.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)? What is unclear about them?

Comment: It's right there in your declaration: an instance of `AddressPrimary` from the array (or `null` if the id is not found).

Comment: Yes I have read the notes. According to the notes what I described in the later part of my question could not happen but it does. So I'm asking.

Comment: Find returns `undefined` if not found not `null`.

Comment: pilchard - assume that it finds what I need it to find.

Comment: When the method does return an `AddressPrimary` object, it is, as is **always** true in JavaScript, a **reference** to the object. Thus if you change a property in the returned object, the object in the array changes also because they are the same object. In other words, `.find()` does not return a copy of the object. Generally **nothing** in JavaScript will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

So the addressFound will be first found element in addressArray with given id. Or undefined if non is found

Answer (score 0):

`Array.find()` returns the first element found in the array and `undefined` if none found.
If you want to get the index of the first occurance of the element then you should use `Array.findIndex()` instead; it will return `-1` if none found.